# How do you modify the CSS using an input box in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**This is the code i am trying to get to work, i could not work out why JQ will not pick up the #cols1 var from the inputbox.**

> This is a basic example of the code i am using.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'>
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function changeCon()
{
var cols1 = $('#col1').value;
$('#div1').html('Random text');
$('#div1').css({ backgroundColor: "#cols1" });
}

function startup()
{
$('#bt1').click(changeCon);
}
$(startup);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id='col1' type='text' /> <br />
<div id="div1">text div.</div>
<input type="button" id="bt1" value="Submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone know's why, it would be great cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this

```
var cols1 = $('#col1').val();
$('#div1').html('Random text');
$('#div1').css({ backgroundColor: "#" + cols1 });
```

or

```
var cols1 = $('#col1')[0].value;
$('#div1').html('Random text');
$('#div1').css({ backgroundColor: "#" + cols1 });
```

Comment: Thanks this has worked. it is a big difference between using: var bcol = document.getElementById("bcols").value; and document.getElementById('div1').style.backgroundColor=bcol; but still learning JQ.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery objects do not have a `value` property (DOM elements representing HTML form controls do). jQuery objects have [a `val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Quentin is right.
2. JS is not PHP, you have to use `$('#div1').css({ backgroundColor: '#'+cols1 });` instead of `"#cols1"`.